# Does Open Graph allow multiple types?

Tags: schema.org, facebook, meta-tags, open-graph-protocol

According to the [OGP documentation](https://ogp.me/#array) it is allowed to have multiple entries of the same tag with different values. In this case, tag properties are read in the order they appear. In the following snippet image, `rock1` has a width and height of 300, `rock2` has no properties, and `rock3` has a height of 1000.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/rock1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/rock2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/rock3.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1000" />
```

**Q**: Is it possible to have multiple types?

Is it possible to have a construction like this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="de" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/article-1.html" />
...
<meta property="og:article:author" content="https://www.example.com/autors/john-doe" /> 

<meta property="og:type" content="profile" />
<meta property="og:profile:first_name" content="John" /> 
<meta property="og:profile:last_name" content="Doe" /> 
<meta property="og:profile:username" content="johndoe123" /> 
<meta property="og:profile:gender" content="male" />
```

Such constructions, in general type arrays, are possible while using structured data of Schema.org - but I can't find anything about this for Open Graph.

I've tried to test such (more completed) code with some debugging tools - this didn't bring me closer to an answer:

- The [FB debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) recognizes only the *first* type,
- [This one](https://issemantic.net/schema-markup-validator) recognizes only *last* type